# How to run Javascript in in an Angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, email

I have this contact form. I want to put on my contact page but I can only get it to work in the index.html file, so it is always at the bottom of the page not just in the contact page. Is there a way to put it in the contact component and the script still work?
This is the form:

```html
   <center>
  <form id="form">
    <span class="field">
      <input type="text" name="to_name" id="to_name" placeholder="name">
    </span>
    <span class="field">
      <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message">
    </span>
    <span class="field">
      <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="email">
    </span>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Send Email" >
  </form>
</center>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    emailjs.init('user_#############')
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  const btn = document.getElementById('button');

document.getElementById('form')
 .addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   btn.value = 'Sending...';

   const serviceID = 'default_service';
   const templateID = 'contact_form';

   emailjs.sendForm(serviceID, templateID, this)
    .then(() => {
      btn.value = 'Send Email';
      alert('Sent!');
    }, (err) => {
      btn.value = 'Send Email';
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});
  </script>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But maybe you should use shared component.

Comment: you could put that js code in the component ts file, and launch it adding (click)="send()" in html button. for btn.value you should bind it using the angular way.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.